# How to write linq query for this SQL query?

Tags: sql, linq

How to write linq query for this  SQL Query

```
select c.Name, Count(cb.Id) as Total1, Count(cf.Id) as Total2 
from Company c 
left join CompanyBDetails CB on C.Id = CB.CompanyId
left join CompanyFDetails CF on CF.BankId = CB.Id
group by C.Name
```

Comment: You should give this a try and post your attempt. I recommend looking at GroupJoin and SelectMany to achieve the left join and using the DefaultIfEmpty to test for left join misses.

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a table of `Companies`, where every `Company` has zero or more `BDetails`, every BDetail belongs to exactly one Company, namely the Company that the foreign key `CompanyId` refers to: a straightforward one-to-many relation.

Similarly, every `BDetail` has zero or more `FDetails`, and every `FDetail` belongs to exactly one `BDetail`, namely the `BDetail` that the foreign key `BankId` refers to.

For every company you want the Name of the Company and the number of BDetails of this company. It seems to me that you also want the total number of FDetails of all BDetails of this Company.

```
var result = dbContext.Companies.Select(company => new
{
    Name = company.Name,

    BDetailIds = dbContext.BDetails
        .Where(bDetail => bDetail.CompanyId == company.Id)
        .Select(bDetail => bDetail.Id),
})
```

Intermediate result: for every Company, you have created one object, that holds the name of the Company, and the Ids of all its BDetails

Continuing the Linq: calculate the totals:

```
.Select(company => new
{
    Name = company.Name,

    // Total1 is the number of BDetails of this Company
    Total1 = company.BDetailIds.Count(),

    // Total2 is the number of FDetails of all BDetails of this Company
    // whenever you need the sub-items of a sequence of items, use SelectMany
    Total2 = company.BDetailIds
        .SelectMany(bDetailId => dbContext.FDetails.Where(fDetail => fDetail.BankId == bDetailId))
        .Count();
});
```

If you want more properties than just the totals:

```
var result = dbContext.Companies.Select(company => new
{
    // Select the company properties that you plan to use:
    Id = company.Id,
    Name = company.Name,
    ...

    BDetail = dbContext.BDetails
        .Where(bDetail => bDetail.CompanyId == company.Id)
        .Select(bDetail => new
        {
             // Select only the bDetail properties of the company that you plan to use
             Id = bDetail.Id,
             ...

             // not needed, you know the value:
             // CompanyId = bDetail.CompanyId,

             FDetails = dbContext.FDetails
                 .Where(fDetail => fDetail.BankId == bDetail.Id)
                 .Select(fDetail => new
                 {
                      // you know the drill by now: only the properties that you plan to use
                      Id = fDetail.Id,
                      ...
                 })
                 .ToList(),
        })
        .ToList(),
});
```

Comment: Hello Harald Thanks for it, can you just explain the same with query expression by using count and  group by clause. I.am new to entity framework and iam not able to join all three tables and count rows using group by in a single query.

Comment: You should have added the Entity Framework Tag. Because that would have resulted in a totally different answer. I don't know why you want to use LINQ GroupBy. Are your requirements are different than you say? It's usually not a good idea to give some code and then say: my code doesn't work, and let us guess what you plan to do. Advice: edit your question, described the relevant parts of your tables and their relations. And describe in words what you want to query. Especially the description in words helps you to create the correct LINQ. Don't try to translate SQL to LINQ